# Operators commuting with an antilinear involution form an algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $f(\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2)=\bar{\lambda_1}f(e_1)+\bar{\lambda_2}f(e_2)$ and $f^2=Id$. Then the operators commuting with $f$ form an algebra, isomorphic to $Mat_{n}(\mathbb{R}).$ This is true?

Comment: The two conditions mentioned correspond to $f$ being _antilinear_ and an _involution_. I've edited the title to include this for reader convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we let $\Re=\ker(f-\operatorname{Id})$, $\Im=\ker(f+\operatorname{Id})$, we have $\Bbb C^n=\Re\oplus \Im$ (as $\Bbb R$-vector spaces), $f\restriction_\Re=\operatorname{Id}_\Re$, $f\restriction_\Im=-\operatorname{Id}_\Im$.
If $v\in\Re$, then $f(iv)=-if(v)=-iv$, and similar $f(iv)=iv$  for $v\in\Im$, i.e., multiplication by $i$ is an isomoprhism $\Re\to\Im$ (and also $\Im\to \Re$). It follows that $\Re\cong\Im\cong \Bbb R^n$.

Any $\Bbb R$-linear map $g\colon\Re\oplus\Im\to\Re\oplus\Im$ is of the form $(v,w)\mapsto (Av+Bw,Cv+Dw)$. Then 
$$ f(g(v,w))=f(Av+Bw,Cv+Dw)=(Av+Bw,-Cv-Dw)$$
whereas
$$g(f(v,w))=g(v,-w)=(Av-Bw,Cv-Dw) $$
For $f\circ g=g\circ f$, we read off the condition $B=C=0$. Hence the $\Bbb R$-linear operators commuting with $f$ form an algebra isomorphic to $\operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)\oplus\operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)$.

If we additionally demanded that $g$ is $\Bbb C$-antilinear (or $\Bbb C$-linear), i.e., $g(i(v,w))=g(-w,v)=(-Aw,Dv)$ equals $-ig(v,w)=- i(Av,Dw)=(Dw,- Av)$ (or $ig(v,w)=i(Av,Dw)=(-Dw,Av)$), the additional condition $D=\mp A$ would make our algebra isomorphic to $\operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

In is clear that such operators form an algebra.  In particular: let $g$ and $h$ be such operators.  Then we have closure under addition
$$
f \circ (g + h) = f \circ g + f \circ h = g \circ f + h \circ f = (g + h) \circ f
$$
and closure under composition
$$
f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h = (g \circ f) \circ h =
g \circ (f \circ h) = g \circ (h \circ f) = 
(g \circ h) \circ f
$$
To see that the resulting (real) algebra is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Mat}_n(\Bbb R)$, it suffices to note that:

- "Multiplication by $i$", i.e. the linear map $x \mapsto ix$ yields an isomorphism between $\ker(f - \mathsf{Id})$ and $\ker(f + \mathsf{Id})$.
- $\ker(f - \mathsf{Id}) \cong \Bbb R^n$
- $g \circ f = f \circ g$ if and only if $g(\ker(f - \mathsf{Id})) \subseteq \ker(f - \mathsf{Id})$
- The real matrices within the complexification of $\operatorname{Mat}_n(\Bbb R)$ are those operators such that $f(\Bbb R^n) \subseteq \Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusions reached in both of the above posts are false. The error in both is the assumption that $\ker(f-\operatorname{Id})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact that space can be trivial. The conclusion on the structure of linear operators commuting with $f$ is also false.

Example. A simple example in terms of the standard basis $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ is
$f(e_1)=\cos(t)e_1+ i\sin(t)e_2$ and $f(e_2)=i\sin(t)e_1+\cos(t)e_2$
extended by anti-linearity to the complex span of $e_1$ and $e_2$. Then $f^2=I$. For this example $\ker(f-\operatorname{Id})=\ker(f+\operatorname{Id})=0$, when $t$ is not a multiple of $\pi$.

For the structure of linear operators commuting with $f$, consider the linear operator $$L, given by $L(e_1)=ae_1 + be_2$, $L(e_2)=de_1+ce_2$, where $a$ and $c$ are real, and $d$ is the complex conjugate of $b$, so that $L$ is self-adjoint. Then $L$ commutes with $f$ if and only if $i(a-c)\sin(t)=(b-d)\cos(t)$. To relate this to answer (1), I think one should set $B=(b-d)e_2/2$ and $C=(d-b)e_2/2$. and observe that $B=C=0$ follows only when $t$ equals $\pi$ or $2\pi$.